# How do we get the rows that contain the max value for the column "Term" in each grouped set

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you get the rows that contain the max value for the column "Term" in each grouped set?

I've seen some overly-complicated variations on this question, and none with a good answer. I've tried to put together the simplest possible example:

Given a table like that below, with Module_Name , Term , and Synopsis columns, how would you get desired result as like below?

### Module_Name | Term | synopsis

Ali  | 2001     | case1
Ali  | 2002     | case2
Ali  | 2002     | case3

Nami | 2101     | Opt1
Nami | 2101     | Opt2
Nami | 2102     | opt3

Desired result set:

Ali  | 2002     | case2
Ali  | 2002     | case3

Nami | 2102     | opt3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution that works using row_number partitioned by module_name. `#test` is your table name

```
WITH tempdata as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY module_name
    ORDER BY term DESC) as RowNumber,
    module_name,
    term,
    synopsis
    FROM #test
)
SELECT td.module_name,td.term,td.synopsis 
FROM tempdata td JOIN #test t on td.module_name = t.module_name and td.term = t.term 
WHERE td.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use *rank* window function:

```
with r as (
  select *, 
  rank() over(partition by Module_name order by term desc) rnk
  from t
)
select Module_name, Term, Synopsis
from r
where rnk = 1;
```

Demo [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f10d9025bc9e3b35036249ba949e765f)

Comment: Thanks it works as expected. Thanks !!!